# Eloquent hasOne vs belongsTo degenerate to same function if both keys are specified?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

For the case of a one-to-one relationship, if I fully specify the keys in the method calls, is there a difference between `hasOne` and `belongsTo` relationships? Or, asked differently, if I used `hasOne` on both sides of the relation, would it be the same result?

Comment: Sorry, this is not an answer. You only stated a conclusion. Pay attention to the detail: "if I fully specify the keys", i.e. the optional arguments to hasOne() and belongsTo().

Answer (score 12):

Yes it works for *some* cases to specify the keys and make the relation work. And with some cases I mean mainly **retrieving** results. Here's an example:

### DB

```
users                profiles
-----                --------
id                   id
etc...               user_id
                     etc...
```

### Models

*Using "wrong" relations with `hasOne` twice*

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    public function profile(){
        return $this->hasOne('Profile');
    }
}

class Profile extends Eloquent {
    public function user(){
        return $this->hasOne('User', 'id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

### Queries

Let's say we wanted to get the user from a certain profile

```
$profile = Profile::find(1);
$user = $profile->user;
```

This is working. But it's not working how it's supposed to be. It will treat the primary key of `users` like a foreign key that references `user_id` in `profiles`.

And while this may work you will get in trouble when using more complicated relationship methods.

For example `associate`:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$profile = Profile::find(2);
$profile->user()->associate($user);
$profile->save();
```

The call will throw an exception because `HasOne` doesn't have the method `associate`. (`BelongsTo` has it)

## Conclusion

Whereas `belongsTo` and `hasOne` may behave similar in some situations. They are clearly not. More complex interactions with the relationship won't work and it's nonsense from a semantic point of view.